Is it within Catholic teaching or theology, to say that someone MUST wear a Brown Scapular?
Looking for some guidance from Catholic theologians or people well familiar with Catholic theology.
Is is okay to say, that someone "must always wear their brown scapular" in order to achieve some desired spiritual end?
Even if this requirement is not on its own, but as part of a number of other well established practices?
For example, "In order to bring the Triumph of Immaculate Heart, one must pray the rosary, consecrate one's life to Mary .... and always wear their brown scapular as a sign of this consecration"

Is it within catholic teaching or theology, to say that someone must wear a Brown Scapular?
The short answer is no.
Like all other private revelations that are worthy of belief, Catholics are not obliged in conscience to follow the dictates of such pious acts of devotion.
Devotions such as the Brown Scapular, the First Friday Devotion, the First Saturday Devotions as well as many more such devotional acts that have been approved by the Church, are not an obligation to fulfill. These devotions nevertheless are encouraged by Holy Mother Church, but the Church leaves it up the the individual faithful to choose whether to follow such acts of pious devotion or not.
This said, such pious acts such as an examination of conscience, are highly encouraged by the Church as this is a direct aide to help us grow in holiness.
Fr. H. G. Hughes gives us some wonderful insights in the article: Devotions Catholics Are Free to Practice (or Not)

No, all private devotions are simply private devotions.
There are about a thousand things that every Catholic needs to do every day.  If we actually did all these things, then we probably would bring the Triumph of the Immaculate Heart.
If everyone:

Goes to Mass on First Fridays
Goes to Mass on First Saturdays
Wears the Brown Scapular
Wears the Scapular and actually prays the scapular prayers
Confesses on Divine Mercy Sunday
Prays the Rosary (the 15 promises will come true)
Prays 30 minutes a day
Prays 60 minutes a day
Does a nightly examen
Prays 3 Hail Mary's before Bed Each Night

All these things are good, they're not all impractical - they may be hard to accomplish altogether - nobody believes they can force God into doing anything.  The notion of "Immanentizing the Eschaton" is abhorrent to Catholic Theology (you can't know the time or the hour) and as Jesus says "the poor will be with you always" so peace AND justice on this earth are impossible.
But, just like knowing God with complete certainty is only done in glimpses, living this authentic Catholic Life in Christ might only happen in fits and starts.  But, that's why it's the Universal Church, there's almost always room for more devotion.

You answer is puzzling as in the first sentence you say "no" you cannot say that a catholic MUST do this, yet in the 2nd sentence you say that there are "thousands things .... NEEDS to do every day", and you list brown scapular as one of those... so I am confused...

@GregBala I'm simply reporting the facts. I don't claim to understand it. However, I think a few things oughta be mentoned. 1. Our Lady said that it was through the Brown Scapular AND the Rosary (not just the Brown Scapular) and 2. The promise on the Brown Scapular is not meant as magic (neither are to promises associated with the Rosary), they're meant as signs of faith - which is why they're sacramentals.  (they really are signs, unlike the Eucharist - a sacrament, which is the Body, Blood Soul and Divinity of Jesus)

I cannot find any reference to "Our Lady said that it was through the Brown Scapular AND the Rosary" ....do you have it ?

@greg yep http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/dominics-prophecy.htm  I don't know if you're skeptical or believing in things like this, but since you asked.  I certainly believe it.  Why people don't wear the brown scapular is beyond me.

yea that is the typical explanation, a combination of private revelations, lots of extrapolations. Don't see a clear message there. but thank you for sharing

@PeterTurner Had to Google "scapular" and to my surprise found a wikiHow How to Wear a Brown Scapular showing 5 steps to use it meaningfully and 4 steps to wear it well.  Are the instructions accurate? Perhaps you you were the author of the wikiHow  ?

@grateful, that's interesting - I like the "it doesn't have to be touching your skin for it to work" part. As if God's grace could be stymied by a bit of polyester!  I think it is debatable whether you're supposed to wear it outside or inside your clothing though.  My guess is, back in the olden days people wore enough layers that the scapular was somewhere inbetween the inner and outer layer.  If you ever watch the Good the Bad and the Ugly, the Ugly guy has one.
